# Selecting class depending on variable

Tags: swift

I have two classes ClassOne and ClassTwo. I want to initialize a different one depending on a variable value, i want to do something like:

```
if(a == "0") {
let b = ClassOne();
}else{
let b = ClassTwo();
}
```

without having to write it everytime I need it. Something like:
let `b = MainClass()`
and gets called `ClassOne()` or `ClassTwo()` depending on the case, a is a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for this to work the two types should be related either by extending a common base class or by implementing the same protocol. Further, subsequent operations on `b` would be restricted to these the two classes have in common.

If you are fine with that restriction, you can do it like this:

```
protocol CommonProtocol {
    func foo() -> Double
    var bar : Int { get }
}
class ClassOne : CommonProtocol {
    ...
}
class ClassTwo : CommonProtocol {
    ...
}
func MainClass() -> CommonProtocol {
    if(a == "0") {
        return ClassOne()
    } else {
        return ClassTwo()
    }
}
...
let b = MainClass()
b.foo()
print(b.bar)
```

**Note:** You could forego all of the above in favor of a completely dynamic approach  by following [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt)'s [advise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36138756/335858).

Comment: There is no need for this, one might argue, as CommonProtocol already exists. It's called AnyObject. But of course (as I've said in my answer) the underlying object must somehow be extracted in order to use it.

Comment: @matt That is definitely true. It doesn't have methods specific to your app, though, so I was reluctant to mention it, even though it lets you call anything on it the `id`-style.

Comment: In my answer, _I_ didn't even want to mention _that_. I would argue that the whole aim here is itself a Bad Smell. :)

Comment: @matt I guess I've been working with statically-typed languages for too long, that's why I prefer a common protocol to `AnyObject`. I would definitely agree that OP's aim is questionable.

Comment: Agreed. Any common protocol (even an empty one) would be better than `AnyObject` here. But I can't imagine any reasonable case (based on the question) where `CommonProtocol` can't be extracted.

Comment: I think @dasblinkenlight is the better solution, but also matt was great. I didn't know how to use protocol, thanks! Hope that question will be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but it isn't going to be useful without further effort. Consider the following:

```
class ClassOne {}
class ClassTwo {}
```

Now we proceed to initialize a variable as an instance of one of these classes. To do so, we must type the variable as AnyObject:

```
var which : Bool { return true /* or false */}
let obj : AnyObject
switch which {
    case true:
        obj = ClassOne()
    case false:
        obj = ClassTwo()
}
```

You now have `obj` as either a ClassOne instance or a ClassTwo instance. But there's a problem. You don't know *which* it is. The AnyObject typing *preserves* the real underlying type (polymorphism), but it also *hides* the type. Every time you use `obj`, you will have to *test* whether it is a ClassOne or a ClassTwo and *cast* it to that type in order to use it.

```
if obj is ClassOne {
    (obj as! ClassOne).doSomethingClassOneKnowsHowToDo()
}
```

The question is: is the pain worth the gain? I would suggest that your desire to do this in the first place is probably a Bad Smell and you should revise your intended architecture. Strict static typing is the point of Swift; you are wrong to want to throw it away.

Comment: Thanks for your replies matt and @dasblinkenlight, i simply want to fetch data from two different sites and so i have two classes that do different things inside functions that have the same name. Have you got some better solutions? Sorry but i'm a newbie in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator to do it quickly, however you do need to do it every time:

```
let b = (a == 0) ? ClassOne() : ClassTwo() //If a==0 let b = ClassOne if not let b= ClassTwo.
```

Answer (score 0):

@dasblinkenlight solution is great but you can also do like this

```
protocol MyProto {
var x: Int { get }
}

class A: MyProto {
var x = 10
var y = 10
 }

class B: MyProto {
var x = 20
 }

class Demo {
 var type: MyProto!

init(str: String) {
    if str == "0" {
        type = A()
    } else {
        type = B()
    }
}
}
```

....

```
let obj = Demo(str: "0").type
 print(obj.x)
```